# How to show Telegram messages in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, telegram

I want to make a flutter app in which I want to get and show messages from particular telegram channel in particular section of that app eg carousel.

Please guide me.

I have made carousel from one flutter package and now want to show those messagew there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.